Do we need a memory acquire barrier when loading a pointer from memory?
In general, we need to use memory barriers(preventing compiler or CPU from reordering memory access) to ensure multi-threaded synchronization, such as:
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

void thread1(void)
{
    x = 1;
    atomic_store_explicit(&y, 1, memory_order_release);
}

void thread2(void)
{
    int tmp_y = atomic_load_explicit(&y, memory_order_acquire);
    int tmp_x = x;

    if (tmp_y)
        assert(tmp_x); // must be ok
}

But there is a situation where I am not sure if a memory barrier is needed, which is difficult to describe. Please refer to the code:
int x = 0;
int *px = NULL;

void thread1(void)
{
    x = 1;
    atomic_store_explicit(&px, &x, memory_order_release);
}

void thread2(void)
{
    int *p = atomic_load_explicit(&px, memory_order_relaxed); // Do we need memory_order_acquire here?

    if (p)
        assert(*p); // is it ok?
}

Or another example:
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int *pv = &y;

void thread1(void)
{
    x = 1;
    atomic_store_explicit(&pv, &x, memory_order_release);
}

void thread2(void)
{
    int *p = atomic_load_explicit(&pv, memory_order_relaxed); // Do we need memory_order_acquire here?
    int val = *p;

    if (p == &x)
        assert(val); // is it ok?
}

My doubts about the last two examples mainly come from two aspects, one is whether the use cases at the C language level pass the assert, and the other is whether these two use cases pass the assert at the hardware level.
I think in x86, this must be passed by assert because x86 does not reorder read operations
But in ARM, I noticed that reads with an acquire barrier are followed by a 'dmb isb' instruction, and I am not sure if using relaxed has any impact. The specific assembly code is as follows:
thread1:
    movw    r0, :lower16:x
    mov r1, #1
    movt    r0, :upper16:x
    str r1, [r0]
    movw    r1, :lower16:px
    movt    r1, :upper16:px
    dmb ish
    str r0, [r1]
    bx  lr
                                        @ -- End function
thread2:
    movw    r0, :lower16:px
    movt    r0, :upper16:px
    ldr r0, [r0]
    cmp r0, #0
    beq .LBB1_3

       # do we need an dmb ish here ?

    ldr r0, [r0]
    cmp r0, #0
    bxne    lr

    # assert failed

.LBB1_3:
    bx  lr
                                        @ -- End function


A release operation without an acquire operation doesn't do anything at all for memory ordering. The only effects of release are in connection with an acquire operation on the same atomic or an acquire fence.

@user17732522 So, in the last two examples, if the assert fails, what could val and *p possibly be?

assert(*p) is a data race and has undefined behavior, same in the second example

Possible duplicate of Do dependent reads require a load-acquire? , although that's a C++ question and this is C.  But their memory models are intentionally compatible.

As a comment under my answer notes, your first example also has a data race and UB, which I overlooked originally. See edited answer.

As mentioned in the other answer, if you load the pointer with memory_order_relaxed, you have a data race, and the behavior of the program is undefined.  Formally, you would be unable to prove, according to the rules of the C memory model (C23 5.1.2.5) that the store to x happens before the load of x via the pointer px.
The typical cause of failure would be reordering in thread2, either via compiler optimizations or CPU memory reordering, such that x is loaded before px.  You might wonder how this is possible, since the program should not know that it's loading from x until it sees the address loaded from px, so this would seem to violate causality.  But it can be done by speculation - the compiler or CPU guesses what the address might be, and proceeds on that assumption, but being willing to start over if it was wrong.  So the code could be transformed, either by the compiler or CPU, to the equivalent of the following:
    int tmp = x;
    // some time passes...
    int *p = atomic_load_explicit(&px, memory_order_relaxed);
    if (p == &x)
        assert(tmp);
    else
        assert(*p);

So now it's entirely possible that x was loaded well before the store of 1 from thread1, such that tmp == 0.
Since C wants to allow for transformations like this, it makes your examples UB, so that the compiler / machine are not obligated to make them work in the "expected" way.

Now, in practice, most real-life architectures will not speculate addresses like this, and so this sort of address dependency would be sufficient to impose the desired ordering, at the level of the machine.  So if one could ensure the compiler doesn't transform it (which, again, memory_order_relaxed does not ensure), then one would not need to pay the price of an acquire barrier in the load of px.
This is the rationale for memory_order_consume, and your examples are the prototypical use case.  Your first example could safely be written as
int *p = atomic_load_explicit(&px, memory_order_consume);
assert(*p); // must pass

because the load of px carries a dependency to *p (5.1.2.5 p14), and this can be used to show that x = 1 happens before *p.
On a platform like ARM64, the compiler would then be able to emit code like
ldr x1, [px] // not ldar nor even ldapr
cbz x1, return
ldr x0, [x1]
bl assert

because the ARM64 spec promises to preserve this dependency.  In Section B2.3 of the Architecture Reference Manual (I'm using version K.a), see the definition of "Address dependency" and how it propagates into the definitions of Ordered-before and Completes-before.
(One example of a machine which does not promise to preserve address dependencies is DEC Alpha.  See for instance Dependent loads reordering in CPU.  On such a system, memory_order_consume actually would need to emit a memory barrier.)
However, this has proved to be very hard to implement in practice, since memory_order_consume can require compilers to refrain from transformations that otherwise seem perfectly innocuous.  As an example, you might think it would be safe (if not efficient) for the compiler to instead emit the following code:
    ldr x1, [px]
    cmp x1, &x
    b.eq is_x
    b is_not_x
is_x:
    ldr x0, [x]
    // ...
is_not_x:
    // ...

But you would be wrong, because the address dependency has been replaced by a control dependency, and ARM64 is allowed to speculate a load through a control dependency.  Basically, it can predict the conditional branch b.eq as taken, and speculatively perform loads on the other side, all before the load from px has completed.
You can come up with sillier examples, like
// thread 1
    array[0] = 1;
    atomic_store_explicit(&atomic_i, 1, memory_order_release);
// thread 2
    int i = atomic_load_explicit(&atomic_i, memory_order_consume);
    if (i != 0)
        assert(array[i-i]); // must pass

which is well-defined.
If the compiler emits naive code like
    ldr x1, [atomic_i]
    cbz x1, skip
    sub x2, x1, x1
    add x3, array, x2, lsl #3
    ldr x0, [x3]

then all is well.  But if it does the obvious optimization of i-i into 0, then it might well emit
    ldr x1, [atomic_i]
    cbz x1, skip
    ldr x0, [array]

which is not okay, because there is now only a control dependency between the two instructions, and the machine can reorder the loads.

For this reason, AFAIK no current compiler actually implements memory_order_consume as intended; they all just treat it as an alias for memory_order_acquire.  So your above example, even with memory_order_consume, likely will just compile on ARM64 to
    ldar x1, [px]   // or ldapr if so equipped
    ldr x0, x1

and you'll pay the cost of the acquire barrier that you didn't truly need.
It was recently reported that for such reasons, the C++ standard committee intendeds to remove memory_order_consume from C++26, so most likely the C standard will also do so someday.  Then you'll have no choice but to use memory_order_acquire.

There are no real-life architectures that do value-prediction for loads (or anything else); it's an idea that's been proposed in computer-architecture, but not implemented commercially AFAIK.  The mechanism for DEC Alpha "violating causality" was different, involving its dual-banked cache somehow.  It's weird enough that I can never remember the details.

Anyway, despite ISO C/C++ failing to expose this hardware feature, Linux RCU uses it on a known set of ISAs and supported compilers with its equivalent of relaxed loads and careful code that won't in practice optimize away the dependency.   see Paul E. McKenney's CppCon 2016 talk: C++ Atomics: The Sad Story of memory_order_consume: A Happy Ending At Last?; also C++11: the difference between memory_order_relaxed and memory_order_consume

A release operation on an atomic object only incurs any effect on memory ordering in relation to an acquire operation on the same atomic object or an acquire thread fence.
If there is no acquire operation on px/pv or acquire thread fence, then the program is just exactly the same as if you had used relaxed ordering instead of the release ordering.
As a consequence the load of *p in both examples is a data race and has undefined behavior.
You need the synchronization incurred by a release/acquire pair on the pointer in order to make sure that the store to x becomes visible to the other thread.
It is also UB in the first example, because x is read without making sure that the store to y is actually observed by the load. Synchronization happens only if the value read by the acquire load is the value written by release store in the atomic object's modification order. Because you cannot guarantee that the load observes the new value instead of the old one, you may still be reading x unsynchronized with its write, causing a data race and UB.
(Note: Everywhere in the above, as an alterative to "acquire", "consume" should be included in the statements as well. I forgot to mention it, partially for the reasons explained by others.)

In the middle example, how does competition occur? In thread 2, since p = pv is an atomic read, p is either NULL or &x.
If p is NULL, assert will not execute; If p is&x , due to the semantics of release, thread 1 has already completed the writing of x at this point.

@untitled "due to the semantics of release,": The semantics of release occur only in relation to an acquire as I stated in my answer. Otherwise it has, in terms of the memory model specification of the language, no effect. That it may or may not cause the implementation to not reorder instructions either way is an implementation detail that doesn't really matter to determine the correctness of the program.

@untitled Even if you look at that implementation point-of-view at the assembly level (which doesn't matter for determining the correctness of the C program), the instructions in the first thread not being reordered, does not mean that the stores become visible in the second thread in the same order. That may be the case e.g. on x86, but that's specific to the architecture as well.

@untitled And on the implementation level this still ignores optimization performed by the compiler that assume that the C memory model rules are not violated. So even if you know that the loads/stores written in assembly without reordering would give the correct behavior and that a release operation will prevent the implementation from reordering, that does not mean that the C program will behave that way.

First of all, thank you for your answer. I understand what you mean now. At the level of C language theory, assert failure is possible
But in reality, it seems that there is no hardware system+compiler that can cause assert to fail
X86 will not exhibit the behavior you described
See Intel ®  64 and IA-32 Architects Software Developer Manual Volume 3a, Section 10.2.3.2

@untitled Arguing that way is really dangerous. You assume that you know that no transformation made to the code by the compiler will invalidate that behavior, but compiler writers are clever and compiler transformations complex. So I do not see how you can be sure that it will behave correctly if it doesn't follow the specification. Suppose for example the compiler is holding x in a register for some reason and replaces assert(val) with assert(x) in your third example.

I understand what you mean, you are right. In the third example, there may be compiler optimization causing assert failure

@untitled In the second as well. The compiler is for example free to replace *p with p == &x ? x : *p with the same problem. Assuming that the compiler won't do that is again putting faith in knowing all the reasons that a compiler might have to perform transformations. Just write correct code according to the specification instead of trying to out-smart the compiler.

I think the assert in the second example is very difficult to fail. Unless x and px are static variables (or lto is enabled), it is difficult for the compiler to make such optimizations.
The second example really confuses me because I feel that there are already many similar practices in open source code.  If I add memory barriers according to the specifications when coding, my code will appear out of place.

Additionally, I am currently working on the assembly of arm32, so whether the sentence dmb ish should be added is currently the most contentious point.
Anyway, thank you very much for your enthusiastic discussion.

@untitled The linux kernel doesn't follow the C memory model. It has its own instead with own implementation of synchronization primitives that rely on behavior that GCC guarantees, but not standard C.

@untitled: Real ISAs other than DEC Alpha do memory dependency ordering for free.  So you're right that dereference of a pointer you loaded atomically can't break, unless the compiler somehow defeats that (like knowing that the only non-null value is &x and optimizing *p into x).  C++ std::memory_order_consume was supposed to expose this hardware functionality, but the design was too hard for compilers to get right so they just promote to acquire.

The Linux kernel for example does take advantage of memory dependency ordering to avoid acquire barriers (especially valuable on ARMv7 as you say, where you don't have ldar or any sufficient barrier that doesn't drain the store buffer).  It does this by making sure to write code where GCC and Clang won't optimize away the dependency.  And since they dropped support for DEC Alpha, they don't use any memory_barrier_depends().  See C++11: the difference between memory_order_relaxed and memory_order_consume for links

@untitled My answer I linked in the last comment answers "Can one replace memory_order_consume with memory_order_relaxed in the example above?" which is a lot like your later examples in this question, with a dependent load.

The first example is broken as well. Reading x before checking the return value of y is UB

@LWimsey Right, I didn't notice for some reason.
